# should we submit the application to nook color and nook tablet separately?

Tags: android, nook, nook-tablet

I have an application I want to deploy it Nook Market,I found two devices NOOK COLOR And NOOK TABLET..Should i need to submit the app in them separatly,,Please help me in this ...

Thanks In Advance

Answer (score 0):

If the app runs fine on both devices, then no, you don't have to submit it separately. You can submit it for both devices at the same time. That's how I submitted my apps to B&N.